# What is the best Poké Puff?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have gotten a Supreme Spring and a Supreme Autumn. I am not 100% sure but they appear to give 5 hearts like the deluxe Poké Puffs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 5 tiers of Pokepuffs. The higher the tier, the more hearts they give when eaten (exception described below). The colours and designs seem to be just for show however

1. **Tier one:** Basic Pokepuffs

   No frosting, no toppings, gives 2 hearts when eaten.

   Gained by doing poorly in easy and normal games.

   Feeds 1 batch of visitors.
2. **Tier two:** Frosted Pokepuffs.

   These have swirly frosting at the top, but no toppings, gives 3 hearts when eaten.

   Gained by doing well in easy, average in normal, or poorly in hard.

   Feeds 2 batches of visitors.
3. **Tier three:** Fancy Pokepuffs.

   These look like the tier one puffs, but have a topping, like a piece of fruit, chocolate, or a cookie stick. They give 4 hearts when eaten.

   Gained by doing well in normal, average in hard and poorly in unlimited.

   Feeds 3 batches of visitors.
4. **Tier four:** Deluxe Pokepuffs.

   These have both frosting and a topping and are worth a whole 5 hearts each.

   Gained by doing well in hard, and average in unlimited.

   Feeds 4 batches of visitors.
5. **Tier five:** Supreme Pokepuffs

   When eaten, they still only give 5 hearts (exception).

   Gained only when 5 starring unlimited modes, and only 2 at a time, on your birthday, when you defeat the Elite 4 or when friends visit you on the Pokemon Amie screen.

   Feeds 5 batches of visitors.

<sub>Sourced from [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696960-pokemon-y/67499155) and [serebii](http://serebii.net/xy/pokemonamie.shtml)</sub>

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful especially for citing your sources.